# Ubuntu sound control menu is not working after upgrading to Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 22.10, pipewire, 23.04

As you can see on the screenshot the sound menu of the Ubuntu settings is always empty, and I am not able to change any sound source or volume, etc.

[image: screenshot]

Meanwhile when I execute `inxi -Fxz`, my audio devices are present.

[image: see here]

I noticed that when I tried `systemctl --user status pipewire-session-manager`, it gives me an error saying `Loaded: error (Reason: Unit pipewire-session-manager.service failed to load properly, please adjust/correct and reload service>`. Reinstalling pipewire did not help. Is there any known solution for this, because I cannot find one so far?

I found out that pipewire-pulse doesn't work at all, therefore the sound panel is empty, but I still can't find why it's not working itself instead of executing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and running this command helped me:

```
sudo apt --reinstall install pipewire-media-session
```

More info in this Ubuntu bug report: [Ubuntu 23.04 mic stop working Edit](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-manager/+bug/2017891)

Comment: That execution prompts me that these packages will be removed. I am not sure it would be good to say yes :/ `The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gdm3 gnome-control-center gnome-initial-setup gnome-shell-extensions
  gnome-tweaks pipewire-alsa pipewire-audio ubuntu-desktop
  ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-session wireplumber
`

Comment: DO NOT RUN THIS COMMAND. As ce4voix has said, it will delete some critical packages including your dsktop GUI!

Comment: THIS ABSOLUTELY REMOVES THE GUI, if anybody does this, they need to run following after then login (in terminal) `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as ce4voix (reinstalling pipewire-media-session would remove my whole Gnome desktop), but instead of going through the rabbit hole of dependencies, I solved it this way:

1. Run

> sudo apt --reinstall install pipewire-media-session

2. Your X server will crash. Restart and login in the terminal
3. Install ubuntu-desktop

> sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop

Done

Sorry I made a new response, but I don't have enough reputation to add a comment.

Comment: I've tried this but it didn't solve my issue. I realized that everything is set but the pipewire session is not started on boot. So that I created a script to start it manually

Answer (score 0):

Installing `pipewire-media-session-pulseaudio` worked for me, on a new upgrade to 23.04.

Comment: I think you made your sound work with reinstalling pulseaudio. This package has been used to make pulseaudio and pipewire work altogether, however since pipewire should work alone after ubuntu 23.04, we shouldn't need that.