# Audio control disappeared after upgrade to ubuntu 23.04

Tags: sound, 23.04

I just upgraded from 22.10 to 23.04 and audio control disappeared.
I tried what was in :[Ubuntu sound control menu is not working after upgrading to Ubuntu 23.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1465169/ubuntu-sound-control-menu-is-not-working-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-23-04) but it did not work for me.
Audio is working, I just cannot change volume.
When I go to the settings, there is no Output device or Input device.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you try `pulseaudio --start` and check if any devices have appeared?

Comment: N: [pulseaudio] main.c: User-configured server at unix:/tmp/pulseaudio.sock, refusing to start/autospawn.